# run time error and object required appeared to me

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this code:

```
Sub protectallsheets()
    Dim singlechart As ChartObject

    For Each singlechart In Subreport.ChartObjects
        singlechart.Chart.SetSourceData Range("B2:B11, D2:D11")
    Next singlechart
End Sub
```

The following error message appears:

> object required

Comment: can you please add the entire error message? which line generate the error?

Comment: Please when you report an error also include *the line of code* which causes the error.  Since we don't have your full working environment, that makes any suggestion we make guesswork. Also, please tell us what `Subreport` is.

Answer (score 0):

An object is not initialized, please try something like this:

```
Sub protectallsheets()
  Dim singlechart As ChartObject
  For Each singlechart in Worksheets("Subreport").ChartObjects

    singlechart.Chart.SetSourceData Range("B2:B11, D2:D11")

  Next singlechart
End Sub
```

To avoid runtime errors you can define an option that will let you know immediately missing variables, to do so, you need to add the following line at the beginning of your script:

```
Option Explicit
```